# How to remove black bar menu from the bottom of android screen?

Tags: android, menu

```
Device: HTC One mini
Android OS: 4.3
app minSdkVersion="8"
app targetSdkVersion="11"
```

I'm building apps for old Android 2.2 phones and higher and have duplicated my menu into a popup window in case newer Androids have issues with it. The black bar bellow shows the lone menu button on a specific device (HTC One mini), but my benefactors want it removed/hidden from the final version.

I wish to keep using the phisical menu button normally on older phones, so it would be best to disable it for specific OS versions or models of phones.

How do you hide/remove the useless bottom black bar? Preferably without raising the targetSdkVersion?

[image: black bar at bottom of android screen]

Comment: did you try to remove calling menu from onCreateOptionsMenu or modify it to not show three dots item

Comment: Yes, I removed all mention to menu from the Activity, and it still showed up. It didn't do anything unexpected, but it was still there. Also tried disabling it in various ways in code, but that didn't help. Looks like many devices (including Google Play installer) just look at the targetSDKversion and use it as an easy shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you hide/remove the useless bottom black bar?

[Set your `targetSdkVersion` to 14 or higher](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/06/08/removing-rogue-menus.html).

> Preferably without raising the targetSdkVersion?

Chop the bottom portion of the phone off with a very sharp axe. Note that this may void your warranty on the phone.